# Azure Functions, nuget package installation failed on West Europe region

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I'm trying to use NuGet in azure function on West Europe region.
I can not install packages.
The reason is "The user name or password is incorrect".
But North Europe region was succeed.
I think this is a problem in the West Europe region.

I created a TimerTrigger(C#).
Upload project.json file

```
{
    "frameworks": {
        "net46":{
            "dependencies": {
                "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights": "2.1.0"
                }
            }
        }
}
```

log

```
2017-10-17T15:11:11 Welcome, you are now connected to log-streaming service.
2017-10-17T15:11:35.816 Package references have been updated.
2017-10-17T15:11:35.816 Restoring packages.
2017-10-17T15:11:35.816 Starting NuGet restore
2017-10-17T15:11:37.535 Restoring packages for D:\home\site\wwwroot\TimerTriggerCSharp1\project.json...
2017-10-17T15:11:37.914 GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights/index.json
2017-10-17T15:11:38.558 OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights/index.json 622ms
2017-10-17T15:11:38.587 GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights/2.1.0/microsoft.applicationinsights.2.1.0.nupkg
2017-10-17T15:11:38.606 OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.applicationinsights/2.1.0/microsoft.applicationinsights.2.1.0.nupkg 18ms
2017-10-17T15:11:38.868 Installing Microsoft.ApplicationInsights 2.1.0.
2017-10-17T15:11:41.577 The user name or password is incorrect.
2017-10-17T15:11:41.577 
2017-10-17T15:11:41.577 
2017-10-17T15:11:41.596 Packages restored.
```

Comment: Please remove the C tag from this post and add whatever tags are actually appropriate.

Comment: I made a mistake. Thank you.

Comment: Did you solve this issue, I faced with it for today too. @TakuyaTeraoka

Comment: When I turn Slots on from function app settings, It was solved.

Comment: I have not solved this problem yet.
However, I confirmed that the problem was solved by enabling the Slots.
I hope the Azure Functions team will be officially resolved.
Thanks.

Comment: This issue was solved.